# How to iterate over arrays in angular 12?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular12

I am trying to iterate over an object that's in an array of an array, however, I'm not able to display the data in the front-end.

I tried this method:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of events of event | keyvalue">
    {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

and this one:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of events of event | json">
   Test: {{item}}
</div>
```

The structure of the JSON data is given in this format.

```
[
    [
        {
            "age": "age3",
            "gender": "gender3"
        },
        {
            "age": "age3",
            "gender": "gender3"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: What about inserting an intermediate `ng-container` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through each internal array as well, so you'll need a nested `*ngFor`. Make sure to reference the correct `item` array in your nested `*ngFor`.

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of events">
    <div *ngFor = "let x of item">
        {{x.age}}:{{x.gender}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks likes a nested array, try using multiple ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
  <div *ngFor="let item of event">
    Test: {{item | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you could try using [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the nested array:

```
this.flattened = this.events.flat();

// ...

<div *ngFor="let item of flattened">
  Test: {{item | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: As OP probably does not want useless DOM element, it would probably be better with a `<ng-container>` instead of a `<div>` for the first layer of iteration

Comment: Definitely possible @ArnaudDenoyelle, you should create an answer showing that.

Answer (score 1):

`<ng-container>` is fine when you want structural logic without polluting the DOM with useless elements.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let subArray of array"> <!-- This does not appear in the DOM -->
  <div *ngFor="let item of subArray"> <!-- This appears in the DOM -->
    {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've upvoted your answer :-)